# Utility Application and View-Based application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I'm new to xcode and the iphone sdk. I've been working with the view-based application for quite a while, and I was wondering if a utility application and a view based application involved the same type of coding. Can someone point out the difference for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The both use the same frameworks, the only difference is how they are set up by default.  The unity template provides a two view application (by default) and the view based only one.

Comment: Thanks Man! So I can combine my coding and it will be alright?

Comment: yea, it SHOULD be.  Sometimes there are unusual bugs that happen, if so then just copy and paste the code in

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Utility application in Cocoa-Touch is just a simple application template for application with 2 views.

This is apparently good for simple apps which have primary screen and configuration screen.
Have a look at [Understanding view controllers in Cocoa Touch](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/268-understanding-view-controllers-in-cocoa-touch/) which has some explanation.

It depends from what point you looking at differences. You still use cocoa-touch for your application. The difference is that simple view based application is a simple template for one screen application, you can extend it as you like. Utility application is simple template for an application with 2 views but you can extend it as you like.